# How to write shorter this "or" statement and is it right?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, bitwise-operators, conditional-statements

```
fail = 0;   

if (masivs[0][0]>0 | masivs[0][1]>0 | masivs[0][2]>0| masivs[0][3]>0 |masivs[0][4]>0| masivs[0][5]>0|masivs[0][6]>0| masivs[0][7]>0|masivs[0][8]>0|masivs[0][9]>0)
{
    fail = 1;
}   
else {
    fail = 0;
}
```

I need to check if in the 0 row is some positive element if yes then need to change fail to 1.

Comment: Why you hate loops ?

Comment: I think you mean `||` (logical or), not `|` (bitwise or).

Comment: There is a not-so-thin line between `|` and `||`.

Comment: You could assign your test expression to `fail` directly and get rid of the `if`..`else`, if you like.  Also normally `||` is more appropriate for things like this (as others suggested)... `|` only works here because the `>` comparisons will only give 1 or 0.

Comment: @P0W: Ask the STL designers, half of their functions exist to replace loops :P

Comment: BTW, why the downvotes? The question is clear enough, and shows a reasonable effort to solve the problem. Sure, the hardcoded element enumeration is a bad idea, _but fixing that is the subject of the question_! The code would deserve a downvote if it was presented as an answer instead of as a problem.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) (C++11) to clearly show your intent. I'll assume you have an array of `int`s. In C++14, however, you could replace the `int` below with `auto` and it would work for whatever type it is.

```
fail = std::any_of(
    std::begin(masivs[0]), std::end(masivs[0]), 
    [](int i) {return i > 0;}
);
```

Make sure the array size is known such that `std::begin` and `std::end` will actually work (i.e., the array isn't actually a pointer).

For a completely pre-C++11 solution, you could use `std::find_if` and if you don't want to write your own predicate, you could use the now-deprecated `std::bind2nd` with the `std::greater` functor to bind 0:

```
int *end = masivs[0] + 9;
fail = (std::find_if(masivs[0], end, std::bind2nd(std::greater<int>(), 0)) != end);
```

Comment: +1. Make sure your C++11 compile option is turned on for this.

Comment: @FredLarson, I made a pre-11 solution. I'm not particularly fond of `bindxxx`, but it's only deprecated because of `std::bind` AFAIK, and that's C++11.

Comment: Why not use `std::begin()` and `std::end()`?

Comment: @GManNickG, I didn't see the part of the question that clarified that the full row was being checked. I'll change it from a note.

Comment: @chris: Oh, I actually just made the assumption. Well, good point. :)

Answer (score 4):

Just use a `for` loop:

```
fail = 0;
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if(masivs[0][i] > 0) {
        fail = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use a for loop to iterate through the columns in the row you want to check.